# ASP.NET web form application User.Identity.Name not working in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using ASP.NET web form application and trying to access User.Identity.Name in one of the page.

However, it is working fine in VS but returns blank in IIS.

Comment: paste your code

Comment: string currentWindowsuser = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

Comment: @hinamnshu try the other way `string currentWindowsuser = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');`

`var userName = currentWindowsuser .Last();`

Comment: Are you using Integrated Windows Authentication? Make sure it is enabled in IIS and anonymous authentication is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using the correct *code* within your application, but the configuration file is not set up for Windows Authentication.

Make sure these portions are within your web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>    <!-- Require everyone to log in -->
            <!-- add specific allow deny for users and roles here -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Once these elements are in place, you can access the logged in user information

```
// this will be in form Domain\Username
string UserIdentity = User.Identity.Name;

// or we can split and grab the second element
string[] DomainAndUser = User.Identity.Name.split('\\');
string UserDomain = DomainAndUser[0];
strung UserName = DomainAndUser[1];
```

[MS: how to implement Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Scott Gu Blog at ASP.NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application)